# Customize halo of a scatter chart so that the center is intransparently colored

Tags: highcharts

This is what I mean by halo:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.states.hover.halo

It seems that "fill", "fillColor" and "color" in or not in "attributes" does not do the job.

As you can see from this jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/s7ff806c/1 The halos are hallow circles which one can see through. I would like the circle to be solid (i.e not be able to be see through).

Comment: _intransparently colored_ is what  ?? not getting

Comment: Define the "center" of the halo. Also be more specific about what you mean by "intransparently colored". If you specify the effect you are trying to achieve, there may be a better way to do it.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear (English is not my native language). As you can see from this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s7ff806c/1/  The halos are hallow circles which one can see through. I would like the circle to be solid (i.e not be able to be see through).

Comment: @Aqqqq i have updated the answer for opacity issue

Comment: @Deep3015 Thank you! Just realizes that I had always put opacity in the wrong place (within "attrubutes").

Comment: @Deep3015 is it possible to set the opacity of stroke independently of the opacity of the fill?

Answer (score 0):

I think intransparently colored means full opaque see [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color/RGBA) how to achieve

in each series give  `color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, 1.0)',` 1.0 means full opaque, in rgba format

```
series: [{
name: 'Female',
color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, 1.0)',
data: [
  [161.2, 51.6],....]
  }, {
name: 'Male',
color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, 1.0)',
data: [
  [174.0, 65.6],...]}
]
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/bs1srL0w/) with Customize `halo`

**Update**

halo opacity can be adjusted see  [Opacity](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cline%3E.states.hover.halo.opacity) from highcharts docs

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/9a7qknb8/) with Opacity adjusted to full

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
        states: {
            hover: {
                halo: {
                    size: 9,
                   opacity:1,
                    attributes: {
                        fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                        'stroke-width': 2,
                        stroke: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
},
```

**Update** ->*set the opacity of stroke independently of the opacity of the fill*

give `'stroke-opacity': .5,` inside attribute

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/9a7qknb8/4/)

```
plotOptions: {
series: {
  states: {
    hover: {
      halo: {
        size: 9,
        opacity: 1,
        attributes: {
          fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
          'stroke-width': 5,
          'stroke-opacity': .5,
          stroke: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }
      }

    }
  }
 }
},
```